# How to add <tr> tag to <table> tag dynamically in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

code in html file is as following:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var records=[{"name":"Fred","id":"123"},{"name":"Jim","id":"456"}];
    </script>
    <table id="tb1">
        <tr id="row1">
            <td style="background-color:gray" id="name">name</td><td style="background-color:gray" id="id">id</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2"><td>shouldn't be added here</td><td>neither here</td></tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

I want to add the contents of records between row1 and row2 in pure javascript.(without any third party javascript framework) What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: well for starters, he has written a malformed JSON `{{"name":"Jim","id":"456"}}` :P

Comment: @AnilShanbhag: That's not JSON. It *is* malformed. :-) Context is king, that's a JavaScript object initializer (or it would be, anyway), since it's in JavaScript code.

Comment: @AnilShanbhag suggestion accepted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't add to "tags," you add to *elements*.

In the general case, you create elements via [`document.createElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-2141741547) (or by assigning a string containing HTML to an existing element's `innerHTML` property).

You add elements as children of other elements using [`appendChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) or [`insertBefore`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727).

So for instance, here's how you could add a row containing two table cells *before* the `id="row2"` in your table:

```
var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
newRow.appendChild(document.createElement('td')); // The first cell
newRow.appendChild(document.createElement('td')); // The second cell
var row2 = document.getElementById("row2");
row2.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, row2);       // Insert it
```

However, as [Heitor points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45519408/157247), for tables there are specific methods you can use instead which are a bit less verbose:

- [`insertRow`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#dom-table-insertrow) on table and tbody/thead elements
- [`insertCell`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#dom-tr-insertcell) on row elements

Here's the code above using `insertCell`:

```
var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
newRow.insertCell(-1);                            // The first cell
newRow.insertCell(-1);                            // The second cell
var row2 = document.getElementById("row2");
row2.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, row2);       // Insert it
```

We *could* also use `insertRow`:

```
var row2 = document.getElementById("row2");            // Get existing row
var newRow = row2.parentNode.insertRow(row2.rowIndex); // Create and insert new row
newRow.insertCell();                                   // The first cell
newRow.insertCell();                                   // The second cell
```

...but then we'd be making changes to the displayed DOM repeatedly (adding a blank row, then adding a cell, then adding another cell), which is better avoided if possible. In the first two examples, we created the row and added its cells before adding that whole structure to the DOM, performing **one** live DOM manipulation.

---

The DOM API can be verbose and a bit awkward, and implementations of it can vary a bit browser to browser (though all of the above is reliable). You obviously *can* use it directly, but you can also use any of several good JavaScript DOM manipulation libraries to get some browser compatibility stuff sorted out for you, and to get a lot of useful utility functionality.

Comment: Assigning a string containing HTML to an existing element's innerHTML property, this is the way I prefer, but how could I make sure the contents string which contains html tag I want to add will between id="row1" and id="row2".

Comment: @kenshinji: You'd create the row element, assign markup for the cells to `innerHTML`, and then insert the row element into the table. But there are browser inconsistencies around tables and `innerHTML` that a good library will handle for you. Side note: It's always best to use a `tbody` element between `table` and the rows (some browsers may insert it automatically). I used `row2.parentNode` above to side-step the possible issue.

Comment: You can just use insertRow method instead! `var row = table.insertRow(0); // to insert in the top` `var row = table.insertRow(-1); // to insert in the bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`insertRow`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#dom-table-insertrow) method, clean and precise!

```
var row = table.insertRow(0); // to insert in the top OR
var row = table.insertRow(N); // to insert in the (N+1)-th line of the table OR
var row = table.insertRow(-1); // to insert in the bottom
```

Comment: `insertRow` is absolutely handy, but for the OP's example, it would be a poor choice because you'd be repeatedly modifying the displayed DOM. Better *in this case* to build the row and cells and then append them all at once. (Its cousin `insertCell` is definitely handy for the OP's case, though.)

Comment: OK I got your point about performance, but it depends on what you're looking for: maximum rendering performance or just a handy piece of code for an urgent small table need.